# How to call one controller method in another controller with RedirectAttributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Code i have written as below.

```
Controller1 {
   @Autowired
   Controller2 controller2
   //Caller method
   void method1() {
      controller2.furnction1(model,redirectattributes);
   }
}

Controller2 {

   public void function1(Model model, RedirectAttributes atr){

   }
}
```

Question is:
How to intialize **RedirectAttributes** (*redirectattributes*)in my new Controller(*Controller1*).
My Controller1 is not a form submit, so that i couldn't get **RedirectAttributes** by default.

How to call the funcation1 in controller2.

Comment: Dosent really look like code! Does it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I have written high level notation.

Comment: how to initialize RedirectAttributes , so that i can pass in the caller method.FYI @RomanC

Comment: You shouldn't be calling one controller from another. You should redirect to a URL instead.

Comment: That is what spring can only do - redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect will not work here. All the form data will be lost. Try forwarding request to another URL.

try something like

```
    Controller1 {

   @RequestMapping("url1")
   public String method1() {
     return "forward:/url2";
   }
}

Controller2 {
   @RequestMapping("/url2")
   public String function1(Model model, RedirectAttributes atr){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion calling a Controller from another Controller is not a good practice. Try using return redirect:/function1 to call the function1 inside Controller2. If it is a common function / service try writing a helper which would do your job.

Answer (score 0):

What RedirectAttributes as to do with POST request ?

Just add it to your first controller method as parameter.

```
 void method1(RedirectAttributes redirectattributes) {
  controller2.furnction1(model,redirectattributes);
```

}

But at the other said, it's not a good pattern, and you should use something like :

```
return "redirect:/some/url";
```